# Write a custom MSE loss function in Keras

Tags: python, python-2.7, keras, loss, mse

I'm trying to create an image denoising ConvNet in Keras and I want to create my own loss function. I want it to take a noisy image as an input and to get the noise as an output. This loss function is pretty much like a MSE loss but which will make my network learn to remove the clean image and not the noise from the input noisy image.

The loss function I want to implement with y the noisy image, x the clean image and R(y) the predicted image:

[image: The loss function I want to implement]

I've tried to make it by myself but I don't know how to make the loss access to my noisy images since it changes all the time.

```
def residual_loss(noisy_img):
  def loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return np.mean(np.square(y_pred - (noisy_img - y_true), axis=-1)
return loss
```

Basically, what I need to do is something like this :

```
input_img = Input(shape=(None,None,3))

c1 = Convolution2D(64, (3, 3))(input_img)
a1 = Activation('relu')(c1)

c2 = Convolution2D(64, (3, 3))(a1)
a2 = Activation('relu')(c2)

c3 = Convolution2D(64, (3, 3))(a2)
a3 = Activation('relu')(c3)

c4 = Convolution2D(64, (3, 3))(a3)
a4 = Activation('relu')(c4)

c5 = Convolution2D(3, (3, 3))(a4)
out = Activation('relu')(c5)

model = Model(input_img, out)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=residual_loss(input_img))
```

But if I try this, I get :

```
 IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

What can I do ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it's quite unusual to use the "input" in the loss function (it's not meant for that), I think it's worth saying:

It's not the role of the loss function to separate the noise. 
The loss function is just a measure of "how far from right you are".

It's your model that will separate things, and the results you expect from your model are `y_true`.

You should use a regular loss, with `X_training = noisy images` and `Y_training = noises`.

---

That said...

You can create a **tensor** for `noisy_img` outside the loss function and keep it stored. All operations inside a loss function must be tensor functions, so use the [keras backend](https://keras.io/backend/) for that:

```
import keras.backend as K

noisy_img = K.variable(X_training) #you must do this for each bach
```

But you must take batch sizes into account, this var being outside the loss function will need you to fit just **one batch per epoch**.

```
def loss(y_true,y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.square(y_pred-y_true) - K.square(y_true-noisy_img))
```

Training one batch per epoch:

```
for batch in range(0,totalSamples,size):
    noisy_img = K.variable(X_training[batch:size])
    model.fit(X_training[batch:size],Y_training[batch:size], batch_size=size)
```

---

**For using just a mean squared error**, organize your data like this:

```
originalImages = loadYourImages() #without noises
Y_training = createRandomNoises() #without images

X_training = addNoiseToImages(originalImages,Y_training)
```

Now you just use a "mse", or any other built-in loss.

```
model.fit(X_training,Y_training,....)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response ! I agree with what you said about the loss function but isn't that correct to say that if I'm using the classical MSE that computes the difference between my noisy_img and my predicted_img, my model will try to minimize this difference and so will try to remove the noise ? And thus, if I want my model to remove the clean_img from the noisy_img in order to get the noise at the output of my model, I have to use a loss function like the one above ?

Comment: No, your model will try to achieve exactly what you give it as `y_training`, which is `y_true` inside the loss function. All you need is to give it the **noise** as expected result instead of giving it a clean image.